# Which were the first iOS devices to charge at faster speeds when connected to a 12W USB power adapter?

Tags: ios, usb, power, lightning

I'm aware that fast charging via USB-C is a relatively new feature for iOS devices - but out of interest, I'm wondering which iOS devices were the first to support faster charging when connected to a standard 12W USB power adapter - either via Lightning, or the legacy 30-pin dock connector.

Comment: Downvoters care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad (4th Gen) was the first iOS device to support faster charging when charged by a 12W (2.4A @ 5V) USB power adapter.

The iPhone 6 was the first iPhone to support the same.

More recently the iPhone 8, iPad Pro and iPad Air (3rd Gen) introduced the even faster USB-PD charging.